# An answer for "how deep is your C# knowledge?"

Tags: c#, .net

If someone were to ask you, a c# developer, "how deep is your C# knowledge?" how would you package your response? (Let's assume you're not Anders Hejlsberg).

Would you talk about features of the language you have used? Namespaces you're familiar with? Certifications or classes you've taken? Lines of C# code you've written? Intimacy with the C# spec?

Comment: *Might* be suitable for http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- .NET namespaces you are familiar with. For instance, System.Net for networking, etc. Of course, related to the required task. Don't go saying you know everything about WPF when you're required to code a console-based server.
- Respect of the C# guidelines (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czefa0ke(VS.71).aspx)
- Language perks and intimacy, how "used" you are to C#. (Special keywords, multi-threading, etc).

In general, anything that proves you have a good and easy understanding of the language, while being able to learn libraries extremely fast due to your comfortability with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As deep as the rabbit hole goes.

I always rephrase questions like that. Becase it is little like saying, how good are you at driving a Mercedes. It's not about the brand of the car. Good drivers drive good whether it's a BMW, Ferrari or plain ol' Opel. Same goes for bad drivers..

A better questions would be, how familar are you with the .NET framwork. Because when it comes to languages, it's mostly just constructs. It's not that hard to learn. The hard part is learning the framework, and all of the libraries it contain.

Comment: The C# language is quite big and complex.  Not as complex as C++ (yet), but increasingly complex with each version.  You could know the .NET class libraries inside and out and still not have a clue about how generic type parameter variance works in C# or how it relates to delegate variance.

Comment: I hardly doubt that you would know the functionality _inside out_ without knowing that.